# Java Android trouble with null point on handler recursion

Tags: java, android, recursion, nullpointerexception, handler

I am having a Null Pointer exception with the following code:

```
void videoCaptureLoop() {
    if (!isRecording) {
        if (videoCaptureThread != null){
            videoCaptureThread.interrupt();
            videoCaptureThread = null;
        }  
        return;
    }

    //Start Video Capture Thread
    if (videoCaptureThread==null){
        videoCaptureThread = new VideoCaptureLooperThread();
        videoCaptureThread.start();
    }

    //Post capture video on 30 fps interval <<<<--------------NULL POINTER ON NEXT LINE
    videoCaptureThread.mHandler.postDelayed(runVideoCaptureLoop, (long) 33.3333333333);
}   

Runnable runVideoCaptureLoop = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        videoCaptureLoop();
    }
};      

public class VideoCaptureLooperThread extends Thread{
    public Handler mHandler;
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception on the line:

```
 videoCaptureThread.mHandler.postDelayed(runVideoCaptureLoop, (long) 33.3333333333);
```

The troublesome thing is I am not sure what is null, I put a break point in but everything looks good, until it crashes, and I haven't been able to see anything different at the break point before a crash.

Does my VideoCaptureLooperThread class look correct? Does it have anything to do with mHandler needing to be static?

error

```
09-28 15:50:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(24931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 15:50:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(24931): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 15:50:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(24931):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.Pcamera.videoCaptureLoop(Pcamera.java:380)
09-28 15:50:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(24931):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.Pcamera$2.onClick(Pcamera.java:338)
09-28 15:50:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(24931):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling videoCaptureThread.mHandler before the new thread has started and initiallized mHandler.

Android provides a class for this, HandlerThread. HandlerThreads are nice because they are instatiated with a Looper. You can use that Looper to create a Handler which will run on the new Thread. You also get to name the new thread, which can be helpful.

Something like this should get you going:

```
//Start Video Capture Thread
if (videoCaptureThread==null||videoCaptureHandler==null){
    videoCaptureThread = new HandlerThread("VideoCapture");
    videoCaptureThread.start();
    videoCaptureHandler = new Handler(videoCaptureThread.getLooper());
}

videoCaptureHandler.postDelayed(runVideoCaptureLoop, (long) 33.3333333333);
```

Answer (score 1):

mHandler gives the nullpointer. mHandler seems only to be declared in VideoCaptureLooperThread.
In videoCaptureLoop(), which is outside videoCaptureLoop, you are refering to mHandler.

Comment: But it's public, aren't all variables shared across threads? And how would I go about fixing it? I just want to create a loop and have it run the runnable off the main UI.

Comment: Yes it is, but have your created a new instance of VideoCaptureLooperThread? (I think you have) and have you executed the run(){} code? The answere above should fix it.

Comment: That is all under "//Start Video Capture Thread" calling Thread.start() calls Thread.run() ... I think you may be correct in the sense that the video thread might not run VideoThread.run() before   the calling thread (UI) calls the mhandler.postDelay(...), but I don't know, I will put in a check for videoThread.mhandler==null and post the delay on the main UI thread if the video thread hasn't started yet. I'll let you know.

Comment: yes that is correct, anyways I added the code I commented about to the answer and checked it off as the correct solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing `mHandler` before method `run` is called, so `mHandler` is not initialized yet. Try initializing it in the declaration itself.-

```
public class VideoCaptureLooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: That might work, but as you have it written mHandler would be a handler on the looper associated with the thread which instantiates VideoCaptureLooperThread. Anyway, I think I got this, There is an error which might have something to do with this thread, but the null pointer error has been bypassed,